# Android Studio onClick Drop Down List Not Populating - Beginner

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Incredibly basic question.

I am following the "hello world" Android Studio tutorial found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) and am having very basic issues.

After creating a function in the MainActivity, the function is not found in the onClick drop down inside of Android Studio.

I have tried setting the function to public, rebuilding the project, synchronizing, and Invalidating Caches/Restarting to no avail.  As a complete beginner to Android Studio I do not know where to look next.

Thanks.

```
package com.example.hcaelxxam.myfirstapp_v2

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun sendMessage(view: View) {
    // Do something in response to button
}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that your code is in Kotlin? What caused the problem for me was that I was using the Kotlin solution when I needed the Java one. Try changing

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    
        /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
        fun sendMessage(view: View) {
            // Do something in response to button
        }
    }
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial?](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

I had the same issue (IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1). I worked around it by:

1. switching the activity editor from Design view to Text view,
2. putting the cursor at the end of (but still inside) the `<Button>` tag,
3. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open up the Auto Complete dialog,
4. selecting `android:onClick`
5. then (inside the double quotes) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again, and choosing (in my case the only option) `sendMessage`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After defining the click method like you did, run a `gradle build` and the opt

Answer (score 0):

Same tutorial, in my case the problem was that the sendMessage() method was commented out in MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add the context into the xml layout for the methods to populate into the editors drop down list for onClick methods. This works in Kotlin as well, java is not required.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```